# Is there a C# framework for parsing and validating CSV/XML files uploaded to an ASP.NET site?

Tags: asp.net, xml, parsing, csv, upload

I have a product-based website and I'd like to expand the number of file formats/layouts that we accept for inventory uploads. Ideally that would be done using some existing implementation that supports various file formats and assists in validating and allowing user corrections to the uploaded data.

Anything giant and "servery" like BizTalk and SSIS are "right out". Hoping someone has come up with something tailored to use in a web site file submission process.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the FileHelpers Library: http://www.filehelpers.net/

Comment: Wow! Thanks, that was quick. 8)

Comment: Oops, no XML handling, flat file specific. Anything that abstracts away the underlying format, loads tabular data from various source types?